# Generate Dates between Date Ranges in mysql

Tags: mysql, cte, date

Is there a way to generate dates between date ranges. After looking on SO I found out there is a way to use CTE, another option is to use Union All from 0 to 9.
Is there an inbuilt function which I can use to generate dates between date range?

We are using MySQL 8.0.

Comment: *Is there an inbuilt function* No. For your version - use recursive CTE.

Comment: Moreover, there is no table data type, so both any built-in function and possibility to create user-definad function with the output of table-type not exists.

Comment: (MariaDB has sequence-generating pseudo-tables.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tried this solution :

```
WITH recursive Date_Ranges AS (
    select '2018-11-30' as Date
   union all
   select Date + interval 1 day
   from Date_Ranges
   where Date < '2018-12-31')
select * from Date_Ranges;
```